# Twilio video mute participant

Tags: twilio

With the new Twilio video API and the absence of the documentation I can't figure out how to mute a participant (even local) in a video call.
Please help.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/

Comment: Thank you, I've already read the docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control the muted/unmuted or the paused/unpaused state of a single `LocalAudioTrack` of `LocalVideoTrack`, you can use the `LocalTrack#enable` and `LocalTrack#disable` methods.

For example, to mute a video track being sent by the local client:

```
var localMedia = conversation.localMedia;
localMedia.mute();
```

Though it would be helpful to know more about which [version of Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) you are using so I might help you find the correct beta docs. If you have any additional questions, I'd love to help you a little more in depth. Shoot me an email to mspeir@twilio.com.

Comment: Oh, thank you, Megan, I've missed that one when looked through the code, so managed to do the same thing through the same code, by accessing _signaling directly, which I knew was bad. Glad you point me to the method

Comment: Is it possible to mute remote participant?

Answer (score 2):

try to like this it's working for me

Unmute :-

```
localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function (audioTrack) {

   console.log("audioTrack-- "+audioTrack);
      audioTrack.enable();
    });
    microphone = true;
```

Mute:-

```
localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function (audioTrack) {
      console.log("audioTrack-- "+audioTrack);
      audioTrack.disable();
    });
    microphone = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.
This code is working for me

```
 $(document).on('click', '.unmutevideo', function() {

    localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(audioTrack) {
        console.log('+++++ audioTrack ' + audioTrack + ' +++++');
        audioTrack.enable();
    });
    microphone = true;
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.mutevideo', function() {

    localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(audioTrack) {
        console.log('+++++ audioTrack ' + audioTrack + ' +++++');
        audioTrack.disable();
    });
    microphone = false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If Possible Participant Audio Track Disable participant audio track disable share code, see below:

```
//Participant is all participant connect with Room. For ex. User-1 Screen Page 
//Participant User-2, User-3 And User-4.

participant.audioTracks.forEach(function (track) {
  if (track.kind === 'audio') {
         track.mediaStreamTrack.enabled = false;
         track.mediaStreamTrack.muted = true;
  }

//sid is disable Audio track Particular Participant sid. For Ex. User-1 Screen 
//Participant User-3 audio disable using audio track sid It is Possible. If 
//Possible give me code or reference URL link.


  if (track.sid == sid) {
        //participant audio track disable.
        track.disable();
  }
});
```

If it is possible give me code or url reference link.

It is possible User-3 screen only user-1 video and audio unable and disable. User-3 screen user-3 as localparticipant and user-1 as remoteparticipant.

Comment: Yes Participant Audio Is Enable and Disable.