# Twilio video -- no video and mute methods

Tags: javascript, twilio

How do you mute and no-video the local participant?
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started

this code has been proposed elsewhere - but is this the track data?

```
var localMedia = conversation.localMedia;
localMedia.mute();
```

So would I get the tracks of the local participant

```
var tracks = Array.from(participant.tracks.values())
```

audioTrack.mute()?
videoTrack.mute()?

```
document.getElementById('button-mute').onclick = function () {
  log('Mute call...')
  console.log('mute call')
  // var localMedia = conversation.localMedia
  // localMedia.mute()
}
document.getElementById('button-no-video').onclick = function () {
  log('No Vid call...')
  console.log('no vid')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You actually want to use the [`disable` method on the local media tracks](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/LocalTrack.html#disable__anchor) to mute them.

First, make sure you're using the [Twilio Video Rooms API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started) (you mention `conversation` in the question, the conversations API is deprecated).

Then, when you connect you can get hold of the local participants media tracks and disable or enable them when you like. Something like this:

```
Video.connect(token, { name: 'room-name' }).then(room => {
  const localParticipant = room.localParticipant;

  $button.on('click', event => {
    localParticipant.tracks.forEach((trackId, track) => {
      if (track.isEnabled) {
        track.disable();
      } else {
        track.enable();
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: wouldn't this disable both audio and video track? - mute and no-vid together

Comment: It would. But I was just writing an example for the answer. If you want different behaviour in your app, then you'll need to work with it to produce that.

Comment: Sweet! Hope the rest of your application goes well :)

Comment: I do have another issue - I am trying to pass the name of the person -- into the participatory json level -- I have identity id's -- but how do I get the name of the person ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059146/twilio-video-chat

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, it worked for me.

```
    // name is video or audio
    vm.toggleMyDevices = function(kind){
        var localMedia = activeRoom.localParticipant;
        localMedia.tracks.forEach(function (track) {
            console.log(track);
            if(track.kind === kind){
                if (track.isEnabled) {
                    track.disable();
                    $scope.isPaused = true;
                } else {
                    track.enable();
                    $scope.isPaused = false;
                }
            }

        },kind);

    }
```

Comment: This just mutes locally, right?  As in, it won't mute for other participants, like, say, the mute for a participant in the audio conference APIs like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128817/twilio-video-mute-participant ?  If the sample above only mutes locally, is there a way to mute a participant for everyone in they room?  Thanks