# Adding a mute button to Twilio Video Quickstart

Tags: javascript, video, promise, twilio

I'm using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033029/twilio-video-no-video-and-mute-methods) as a guide on how to add a mute button to my Twilio video Quickstart application.  I'm still not able to mute my local participant microphone, however.  I added the following code as a promise in my video connection, but it's not even logging the message to the console when I click on #button-mute.

On connecting, the console outputs the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'localParticipant' of undefined

```
Video.connect(data.token, connectOptions).then(roomJoined, function(error) {
        log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
    }).then(room => {
        const localParticipant = room.localParticipant;

        $button-mute.on('click', event => {
            localParticipant.tracks.forEach((trackId, track) => {
                console.log('In mute function code');
                if (track.isEnabled) {
                    track.disable();
                } else {
                    track.enable();
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue here seems to be the return value of your promise. The first part of your code here looks like this:

```
Video.connect(data.token, connectOptions).then(roomJoined, function(error) {
    log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
}).then(room => {
```

If your `roomJoined` function doesn't return the `room` object then the following `then` will not have an argument of `room` and calling `room.localParticipant` will result in your error.

Ensure that `roomJoined` returns the `room` object and it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I'm very close I believe.
I'm now getting the following error when clicking the button:

`In mute function code [LocalAudioTrack #1: 6dcf670e-848b-4862-b208-e5548fbbf183] 6dcf670e-848b-4862-b208-e5548fbbf183
Uncaught TypeError: track.disable is not a function`

It seems like I'm most likely calling the disable function on the wrong object.

Comment: FYI: changed the console output to `console.log('In mute function code ' + trackId + " " + track); `

Comment: What type of object are you seeing as the `track`? It should be a `LocalVideoTrack` or `LocalAudioTrack` and have the `disable()` method. What are you seeing in your logging?

Comment: There's nothing in the on-page log that indicates any error.  And I believe it's a [LocalAudioTrack #1: 6dcf670e-848b-4862-b208-e5548fbbf183].

** Edit: I was confusing the track var with the TrackId var, calling disable on TrackId worked. **

Comment: Ah, glad you got it sorted!